# Form Post Preview On the fly using .net mvc 3 like in stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, jquery, live

I want to develop a live preview of form post similar to stackoverflow. I am using .net mvc 3.

I need some help to do that.

Thanks 
Yohan

Comment: @yohan.jayarathna Check http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: I found something called "knockoutjs asp.net mvc 3". But I have no clue to use that. What is the best and easiest way to implement this functionality ? Thank you!

Comment: @Ravi I have accept questions that I got the answers. How can I accept a question without getting a proper answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the highest level:

1. Set a listener on the text area to wait for keyup events.
2. When a key event is triggered, have a callback re-parse the text in the box.

So, StackOverflow uses markdown or some variant thereof. The quickest way would be to have a client side markdown parser such as http://www.showdown.im/ ( Source code is offline at the moment so : https://github.com/coreyti/showdown ).

Another way would be to have a preview button which passes the text in the box to the server which does the parsing, and passes back a reformatted result which the user can check to then submit. Not as quick and direct as the client side option, but saves loading a big chunk of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery plugin for previewing HTML written by Phil Haak.  You cam use it or refer to the source code for your implementation.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/15/live-preview-jquery-plugin.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/15/live-preview-jquery-plugin.